# How to prevent iPhone application from shutting down or crashing abruptly?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

My iPhone application crashes at some point of time during execution.I don't want the application to terminate abruptly,i wish to show an alert message like "Sorry the application encountered an error" and when pressed ok in the alert view the application should close.

Are there any exception  or error handlers which i can use in my appdelegate file?

Kindly advise me..

Thank you for one and all.

Comment: ",i wish to show an alert message like "Sorry the application encountered an error"" - actually, what you really want is to find and remove the bugs in your code!!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Hii people,

i experience a Same situation where i have to post crash data to dev server when app gets crahsed while running - its useful for us to track of app performance for dev concerns - what's the choice?

i) if we use TRy / catch then its impossible to write in all codes of view with Try/Catch Block?

so ther's some library which you can declare in your appDelegate Class only - where it will alert you whatever crash / error happens in any part of the app.

we write our own Library for people new Try this-

http://code.google.com/p/plcrashreporter/

Answer (score 1):

You can handle crashes in your application in the following way

```
NSArray* testArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];

@try 
{
  // Attempt access to an empty array
  NSLog(@"Object: %@", [testArray objectAtIndex:0]);

}
@catch (NSException *exception) 
{
  // Print exception information
  NSLog( @"NSException caught" );
  NSLog( @"Name: %@", exception.name);
  NSLog( @"Reason: %@", exception.reason );
  return;
}
@finally 
{
  // Cleanup, in both success and fail cases
  NSLog( @"In finally block");
  // Show alert to user

  UIAlertView *crashAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"FAILED" 
                                                    message:@"Sorry. error occured" 
                                                    delegate:self 
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [crashAlert show];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I think you can try `@try` and `@catch`. But using it is in your hands.

A try/catch block is there to catch an exception and stop it from propagating upwards in your callstack.

The idea goes that you catch it at the place where you know how to handle it, and then you get a chance to execute code in response to the exception.

It is not a magical solution that will prevent anything, it is just what I said above. What you do with the exception is what matters.

Also, yes, in a way you can keep your program from crashing by adding try/catch blocks all over, but the only thing you've succeeded in is to hide the crash from the user, and then let the program continue running. "Crashes" are not always safe to ignore, or rather, they are usually not safe to ignore.

If you are looking for some catch-all advice on how to avoid a program crashing, here's my advice:

- **Write a program that works correctly**

**Reference**

[Can the try...catch mechanism be used to avoid memory crashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683987/can-the-try-catch-mechanism-be-used-to-avoid-memory-crashes)

Comment: I think if he can find where to put try and catch blocks, he can surely find and fix those crashes which is the ideal way..

Comment: 7KV7 ,, your try about tryCatch will be go in vain :) this answer won't be mark as answer